# How can I get a list of deleted videos via the youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

Is there a way to find a list of videos that have been removed from a youtube account?

I am using the youtube api to list all videos for a youtube account.

I originally load all videos contained within the users 'uploaded' playlsits. After completion I Poll every day to check if there are any videos that have been added after the last video I retrieved. This means if any videos are added they will be returned.

I am storing all of these videos within my program.

However I cannot find a way through the Youtube data API to retrieve a list of all videos that have been deleted / all videos that have been deleted since a certain point in time. I am going with public method rather than requiring authentication.

I don't want to have to do a check on all videos within the system to check they still exist, but if the video does not exist an error is displayed within youtube.

Is there such a call in the youtube api to return deleted videos since a point in time?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of. And there are many ways a previously public video can no longer be seen.

When a video is deleted by the user, the status is changed to 'DELETED' for a time before the video is completely removed from YouTube.

A video can also be REJECTED by YouTube for violations and removed.

A user can change the status from PUBLIC to PRIVATE.

etc.

If you are using WordPress I would recommend the plugin Video Link Checker.

Comment: >When a video is deleted by the user, the status is changed to 'DELETED' for a time before the video is completely removed from YouTube. 
Is this documented somewhere? Never heard about that kind of logic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the api would be able allow this after they delete it, but if you have the list already such as Video1, Video2, Video3, and they delete it, you should be able to search for the list you have already and find that one of the videos is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if there was a method I didn't spot that returned the deleted content. Almost like a recycling bin playlist. It would have just saved looping through 10k videos to check if they all exist.

Comment: I guess a simple way to test if it's possible to return it would be to test it on your account? Just upload a few seconds worth of footage for like 3 or 4 videos, have it snoop your channel and then set one hidden or delete it and see what it does.